# How to update values of HashMap fields of objects cached in Coherence?

Tags: distributed-caching, oracle-coherence

There is a java bean with following `Map` field:

```
private Map<String, Long> items;

public Map<String, Long> getItems() {
   return items;
}

public void setItems(Map<String, Long> items) {
   this.items = items;
}
```

Is it any chance to get this `items` field updated for objects cached in a Coherence distributed cache using [Coherence Query Language](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15723/api_cq.htm#COHDG5263)?

Something like:

```
update "order-cache" set items = new HashMap<String, Long>() {{put("001",2L);}} where key()=”1”
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) `ImmutableMap`:

```
update "order-cache" set items = com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of("001",2L) where key()="1"
```

This solution is good only for objects with **up to 5 items** in the `HashMap` field.